# Can't send E-mail with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm work using VBA for sending Email automation.When E-mail send it not attach file to Email.

This's my some VBA code :

```
   Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

       iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
       Set Flds = iConf.Fields
       With Flds
          .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
          .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "10.45.1.25"
          .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
          .Update
       End With
       Dim Result() As String
       Dim xAttaches As String

      Result = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(xAttached), "|")

  With iMsg
      Set .Configuration = iConf
      .To = "Veerachai.M@ngerntidlor.com"
      .CC = 
      .From = "finrobo@ngerntidlor.com"
      .Subject = xSubject
      .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & strBody
       For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
         xAttaches = "R:\ASMP\00_AP_AUTO_MAIL\202003\BARCODE\IE238182.pdf"
        If objFSO.FileExists(xAttaches) Then
          iMsg.AddAttachment "R:\ASMP\00_AP_AUTO_MAIL\202003\BARCODE\IE238182.pdf"
        End If
     Next i
      iMsg.Send
  End With

  With Application
      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

  Set iMsg = Nothing
  Set iConf = Nothing
  Set Flds = Nothing
End Function
```

My code can run and can send Email. Like this :

[image]

But I need Attach file in E-mail.Like this :

[image]

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: From what i can see, you have to provide username and password when attempting to attach a document with CDO (i.e. `iMsg.AddAttachment <URL As String>, <Username As String>, <Password As String>`). You can provide blank username and password. Does that help? Never used CDO myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use CDO.Message. If you use Outlook for sending e-mail there is a simple way using default Outlook Objects:
All you need is pick "Microsoft Outlook Object Libary" in VBA Editor -> References; then you will have access to all Outlook object model.

```
Sub MailExcelVbaOutlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = "example@example.com" 
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = "" 
        .Subject = "Topic" 
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\file.txt") 
       .Display or .send
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Because `CDO.Message` is better and more flexible and doesn't need an instance of Outlook installed.